# elasticsearch.logQueries no effect in kibana config

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to log all queries from kibana. So I edited `config/kibana.yml` and added the following lines:

```
logging.dest: /tmp/test.log
logging.silent: false
logging.quiet: false
logging.verbose: true
elasticsearch.logQueries: true
```

Then I restarted kibana, queried for something.

[image]

Now logs start to appear, but only access logs are recorded, no ES queries there.

```
{
  "type": "response",
  "@timestamp": "2018-08-21T02:41:03Z",
  "tags": [],
  "pid": 28701,
  "method": "post",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "req": {
    "url": "/elasticsearch/_msearch",
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      ...
    },
    "remoteAddress": "xxxxx",
    "userAgent": "xxxxx",
    "referer": "http://xxxxxxx:8901/app/kibana"
  },
  "res": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "responseTime": 62,
    "contentLength": 9
  },
  "message": "POST /elasticsearch/_msearch 200 62ms - 9.0B"
}
```

Any ideas? I'm using ELK 6.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `elasticsearch.logQueries` setting has been introduced in Kibana 6.3 as can be seen in this [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/19520)